# Ember.Select -- selected value

Tags: ember.js

Using Ember.Select, I am successfully rendering my dropdown menus

```
{{view Ember.Select
     content=businessType.acceptableValues
     optionLabelPath="content.name"
     optionValuePath="content.value"
     prompt=businessType.prompt
}}
```

The controller pulling the data from the model looks like:

```
businessType: function(){
        var content = this.get('content');
        return content.get(10);
    }.property('content')
```

I can't figure out how to set the selected value. I have tried setting the value to content.value, I have tried selectionBinding=content.value, but nothing is working for me. What am I not understanding for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Look at http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Select.html document.

It says:

> The value attribute of the selected  within an Ember.Select
>   can be bound to a property on another object:
>
> ```
> App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
>   programmers: [
>     {firstName: "Yehuda", id: 1},
>     {firstName: "Tom",    id: 2}
>   ],
>   currentProgrammer: {
>     id: 2
>   }
> });
>
> {{view Ember.Select
>        content=programmers
>        optionValuePath="content.id"
>        optionLabelPath="content.firstName"
>        value=currentProgrammer.id}}
> ```
>
> Interacting with the rendered element by selecting the first option
>   ('Yehuda') will update the id of currentProgrammer to match the value
>   property of the newly selected .

So you just have to bind some existing object property to Ember.Select `value`.

Comment: understood. So if I took that example appended currentProgrammer:{id:2} to my controller and then in the Ember.Select add value=currentProgrammer.id I would think that it would work. But it does not. Here a https://gist.github.com/bungdaddy/11361635